# Sort a column with two different datetime format

Tags: linux, date, sort

I have a tab separated file and the date columns contains date with two different formats. I am using this sort command to sort by one format type ("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"), but is there any way to sort by the date column regardless of it is format? Thanks!

Input

```
date
Mon Mar 02 03:56:26 UTC 2020
2020-03-03 15:46:52

sort -t$'\t' -k 3.25,3.28n -k 3.5,3.7M -k 3.9,3.10n -k 3.12,3.13n -k 3.15,3.16n -k3.18,3.19n sample.csv
```

Comment: Do you want to keep both formats? You could convert your first format to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and sort lexicographically (`sort -k3,3`).

Comment: @Freddy Not necessary. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert both formats to something unambiguous like epoch time, sort on that, then discard. For example, using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
mlr --tsv put '
  $epoch = ($date =~ "^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]") ? strptime($date,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y") : strptime($date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
' then sort -n epoch then cut -f date input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert your `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"` format (or any other format that is recognized by `date -d`) 
to `%F %T` (`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`) using `awk` and the `date` command.

The field number to convert is given in awk variable `col` and the field is skipped if it is already in the correct format.
Well, you can remove the check, but obviously that would make the script slower.

```
awk -v col=3 '
  BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }

  # or remove the check and begin the next line with an opening `{`
  $(col) !~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/{
    cmd="date -u -d \"" $(col) "\" +\"%F %T\"" 
    cmd | getline $(col)
    close(cmd)
    $0=$0
  }
  1
' infile > outfile
```

Then use a lexicographic sort on the desired field, e.g. `sort -t$'\t' -k3,3 file`.

Comment: I added the `-u` option to convert the time to UTC, remove it if you need your local time.